# Not able to access store on non react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

The redux `getState` method is not available. Do I need any middleware for achieving the desired result. Following is the code

```
const configureStore = (initialState = {}) => {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  );
};

export default configureStore;
```

**util.js**

```
import store  from '../../store';

store.getState()

// _store2.default.getState is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a function instead of your store. Seems like you have mixed up reducers with the store. What you want is this:

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
);


export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you intended to, at some point, initialize the store.

I'm not sure how you want to layout your app, but

```
// index.js

import configureStore from 'store';

export const store = configureStore({ ... someInitialState });
```

then

```
// util.js

import store from 'index';

// use store
```

I don't think this is the best solution - instead of exporting an store initializer from `store`, just initialize the store and export the store.